# Unchase OpenAPI Connected Service Error: The type initializer for 'LiquidTemplate' threw an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, swagger, openapi

I am using Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Services VS 2022 extension to generate C# Client class for the APIs (.NET Core). I am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'LiquidTemplate' threw an exception..
```

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstalled and re-installed the extension.
2. Updated VS 2022.
3. Repaired VS 2022.

None of the above solved the issue. I have no clue about the above error and able to find nothing about it from any documentation on the web. Here is the entire log:

```
[06-06-2023 15:25:49.330] Warning:Failed loading the Unchase.OpenAPI.ConnectedService_Settings.xml user settings
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.894] Adding Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Service to the project.
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.894] Adding service instance for "https://localhost:7212/api/swagger/v1/swagger.json"...
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.899] Adding Nuget Packages for OpenAPI (Swagger) CSharp Client...
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.907] Nuget Package "Newtonsoft.Json" for OpenAPI (Swagger) already installed.
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.911] Nuget Package "System.Net.Http" for OpenAPI (Swagger) already installed.
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.916] Nuget Package "System.ComponentModel.Annotations" for OpenAPI (Swagger) already installed.
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.921] Nuget Packages for OpenAPI (Swagger) CSharp Client were installed.
[06-06-2023 15:27:00.925] Generating NSwag-file for OpenAPI (Swagger)...
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.358] NSwag-file "AMSClient.nswag" for OpenAPI (Swagger) was generated.
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.361] Generating Client Proxy for OpenAPI (Swagger) Client...
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.555] Warning:Error: The type initializer for 'LiquidTemplate' threw an exception..
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.567] Client Proxy for OpenAPI (Swagger) Client was generated.
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.571] Adding service instance complete!
[06-06-2023 15:27:03.682] Finished adding Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Service to the project.
```

Although it says its finished adding the connected service, the Client is not updated. Any help or pointers towards debugging this issue?
Visual Studio edition: VS 2022 Professional

Comment: Hi, you can try to delete the project's .vs file and run Visual Studio as administrator. If it still doesn't work try another version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now on the list in GitHub: https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.OpenAPI.Connectedservice/issues/86

As indicated there also: reverting to a previous version is a temporary work around. Please bear in mind to disable automatic updates on Visual Studio Extension until there is a fix released by Unchase.